# Laravel Policies for nested shallow ressources

Tags: php, laravel

I have a the following routes defined:

```php
//Leases
Route::resource('properties.leases', LeaseController::class)
        ->only(['show'])
        ->shallow();

//Invoices
Route::resource('leases.invoices', InvoiceController::class)
        ->only(['index', 'show'])
        ->shallow();
```

The above generates the following urls:

```
| GET|HEAD  | leases/{lease}                                             | App\Http\Controllers\LeaseController@show                                       |
| GET|HEAD  | leases/{lease}/invoices                                    | App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController@index                                    |
| GET|HEAD  | invoices/{invoice}                                         | App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController@show                                     |
```

The relationships are as below:

```
Properties hasMany Leases.
Leases hasMany Invoices.
```

I am trying to authorize these routes, so only users who:

1. Belongs to the same team that the "Leases" and "Invoices" also belong to.
2. Is currently logged in on that team.

In my `AuthServiceProvider` I have defined the following policies:

```php
protected $policies = [
    Lease::class => LeasePolicy::class,
    Invoice::class => InvoicePolicy::class,
];
```

In my `LeaseController` I have defined the authorization check:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Lease::class, 'lease');
}
```

The `LeasePolicy` looks like this:

```php
public function view(User $user, Lease $lease)
{
    //Does the current user belong to the team that the lease is associated with
    //and is the user's current team the same one?
    $team = $lease->property->team;
    return $user->belongsToTeam($team) && $user->isCurrentTeam($team);
}
```

And in my `InvoiceController` I have defined this:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Invoice::class, 'invoice');
}
```

The `InvoicePolicy` looks like this:

```php
/**
 * Path: leases/{lease}/{$invoice}
 */
public function viewAny(User $user)
{

    //When users go to this path I can only access $user here. 
    //How to check if the user can even access the $lease.

}

/**
 * Path: invoices/{$invoice}
 */
public function view(User $user, Invoice $invoice)
{
    //Does the current user belong to the team that the lease is associated with
    //and is the user's current team the same one?
    $team = $invoice->lease->property->team;
    return $user->belongsToTeam($team) && $user->isCurrentTeam($team);
}
```

In my application, I have a lot of routes that are "under" the `/lease/{lease}/{model}` route, e.g.:

```
//Files
Route::resource('leases.files', FileController::class)
        ->only(['index'])
        ->shallow();
```

For these, how can I define my `Policies` so only users who are allowed to view these ressources can get access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know at the time I wrote this answer, the `authorizeResource` cannot be used on some shallow nested methods (such as the `index`, `create`, & `store`). So instead, you can call `authorize` function on each method [via controller helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers).

Or if you still want to use `authorizeResource`, you can only call `authorize` manually on some shallow nested methods like the following example:

```php
class InvoiceController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(Invoice::class, 'invoice');
    }

    /**
     * Get the map of resource methods to ability names.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function resourceAbilityMap()
    {
        return collect(parent::resourceAbilityMap())
            ->except(['index', 'create', 'store'])
            ->all();
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Lease $lease
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Lease $lease): Response
    {
        $this->authorize('view', $lease);

        ...
    }
}
```

And by the way, if you want to make `InvoicePolicy` simpler, you can also reuse `LeasePolicy` like the following code:

```php
class InvoicePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function __construct(
        protected LeasePolicy $leasePolicy,
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Invoice  $invoice
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function view(User $user, Invoice $invoice): bool
    {
        return $this->leasePolicy->view($user, $invoice->lease);
    }
}
```